# Menubars missing in libreoffice when used in unshare session in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice, dbus

When using libreoffice inside `unshare -m` session, the menubar is missing.

In the console output I see these warnings:

```
** (soffice:9193): CRITICAL **: 10:29:29.171:
void g_lo_menu_insert_section(GLOMenu*, gint, const gchar*, GMenuModel*):
assertion 'G_IS_LO_MENU (menu)' failed

(soffice:9193): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 10:29:29.171: 
gtk_menu_bar_new_from_model:
assertion 'G_IS_MENU_MODEL (model)' failed
```

In my normal session, the menubar appears correctly. Also this used to work before I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by apparmor denying access to DBUS socket.

This can be seen in `dmesg` output:

```
audit: type=1400 audit(1542789068.289:1060): apparmor="ALLOWED"
operation="connect"
info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path"
error=-13 profile="libreoffice-soffice" 
name="run/user/1000/bus" pid=9545
comm="soffice.bin" requested_mask="wr"
denied_mask="wr" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
```

I didn't find out how to fix the actual problem with the apparmor rules, but here is how one can disable the apparmor completely for libreoffice. This has some security risks if you open untrusted files.

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.libreoffice.* /etc/apparmor.d/disable/
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.libreoffice.*
```